# Oscillator with low frequency drift

Tags: microcontroller, oscillator, high-frequency, pll

I need a ~70MHz oscillator with low frequency drift (less than 1%) over a wide temperature range (10°C to 50°C).

I dont have any experience with oscillators, so I have no idea which type of oscillator I should use:

- Colpitts Oscillator
- PLL Clock multiplier (e.g. [ICS501](https://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/Renesas-Electronics/501MLF?qs=SmUuHNCnbloK0FQgTG604w%3D%3D))
- Crystal oscillator (e.g. [this one here](https://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/ABRACON/ASFL1-64.000MHZ-L-T?qs=jv7ULIbIBgMDABnFUfvkOQ%3D%3D))
- Silicon oscillator (e.g. [LTC6903](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc6903.html%5D))

I have access to a microcontroller, so I think the simplest solution will be just generating a clock signal and then multiplying it by using a PLL?

I dont care about the wave form, and I dont need to adjust the frequency -- fixed frequency is fine.

Comment: Just off the cuff I'd say you want a crystal oscillator. Even relatively pedestrian crystal oscillators have a spec of about 100 ppm / K. You've got a 40 K range so this (back of envelope) estimate says to expect 0.4% over that range. There's another issue perhaps. That's initial accuracy and how stable that is over accumulation of time and temperature changes and/or changes due to varying atmospheric pressure and/or humidity. I generally trust manufacturer specs related to precision far more than I trust a manufacturer's spec for accuracy. I rarely take an accuracy spec for granted.

Comment: @jonk crystals are much better than 100 ppm/K. They are usually +/-100 ppm across a full range of temperatures.

Comment: @Andyaka Yup. My brain was on vacation! Thanks for the correction!! I was just thinking of the 100 ppm spec and I made up the "per K" out of whole cloth. My apologies for my confusion. BenK, crystals will be a lot better over temperature variation than I mentioned. Andy is right!

Comment: It happens to the best of us. Made the same identical mistake as you (also on SE) do'h

Comment: For even better temperature stability use a [oven-controlled crystal oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_oven).